# How to skip the scan for test files on few modules in a multi module project while using Sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops

I'm setting this property `<sonar.tests>src/test/java</sonar.tests>`
 in the root pom file, the project consist of 7 modules, 5 modules have test cases in the mentioned location, while the other do not have tests, so the sonar scans and  fails as shown :

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  40.072 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-13T01:38:06-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project sch: The directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonar-sch/anonymization/src/test/java' does not exist for Maven module com.interset:anonymization:jar:6.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Please check the property sonar.tests -> [Help 1]
```

How can i skip the scan for tests on the 2 modules or any other workaround would help too, as ill need that property for the code coverage, Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to specify `<sonar.tests></sonar.tests>` in the modules without the test folder?

Comment: @Christopher yes it worked, Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: Specify `<sonar.tests></sonar.tests>` in the modules without a test folder to remove the test folder property.